# Change maximum number of sessions for tmux

Tags: tmux

Is there a limit for number of concurrent sessions created by tmux?
Is this limit configurable or hard coded?
I already looked at this but could not find what I am looking for:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/tmux.1.html#options

Here is the error I get when try to create many tmux sessions:

```
create session failed: : Too many open files
```

Comment: That's not a tmux error; that is the file descriptor limit per process on this machine.

Comment: Thanks!. I change the number of files per process using ulimit -n <number> and it fixed the issue.

Comment: How many sessions are you trying to create? :)

Comment: 300ish. This is used as part of automated test system and each session keeps track of a test session. Valid question though :)